# How to determine type of Schema?

Tags: tom.net

I am trying retrieve a list of Normal and Multimedia Schemas from a given Publication context.  So far I have:

```
RepositoryItemsFilter filter = new RepositoryItemsFilter(engine.GetSession());
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Schema };
filter.Recursive = true;

Publication pub = this.GetPublication();
foreach (Schema schema in pub.GetItems(filter))
{
    //need to further refine to only use Normal and MM schemas
}
```

This is usually not a problem when we are working with a Component because we just do `ComponentType.Normal` or `ComponentType.Multimedia`.  But how do we do this if we only have a Schema?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the `schema.Purpose` which gives you an enum (`SchemaPurpose`) this gives you access to all the schema types including:

- Component
- Multimedia
- Embedded
- Metadata
- Protocol
- TemplateParameters
- UnknownByClient
- VirtualFolderType

Comment: Taking that one step further, there is actually a SchemaPurposes property on the filter that you can use to only get the types of Schemas you are looking for (using this enum). That way, you don't have to do this in a loop after retrieving all Schemas.